# How to stop an Azure function running locally my windows 10 environment

Tags: eclipse, azure, azure-functions

I am creating an Azure function in java and running locally as of now referring this exmaple https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-java-maven.
I am able to run it successfully. Maven commands have package,run which runs the function on my windows 10.

The only way I know now to stop the function is kill the process in Task manager.
There should be a better way to do this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have used the eclipse console kill (Red button) , but no effect.

Comment: Did you try Ctrl-C in the terminal to stop the function code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Eclipse, the `Terminate` button on Console is to terminate JVM and has no influence on the external tool `func.exe` launched using mvn plugin.

Find two workarounds for you to refer. Install plugin `TM Terminal`(search in Help>Eclipse Marketplace) first for convenience.

1. Use command line to kill the process. Right click on project> Show in Local Terminal> Terminal, input `TASKKILL /IM func.exe /T /F` to kill `func.exe`.
2. Run function in terminal hence we can terminate it.

   1). Right click on project> Show in Local Terminal> Terminal

   2). Input `mvn azure-functions:run`.

   3). Input `Ctrl+C` and `Y` to terminate functions.

   4). To debug, run `mvn azure-functions:run -DenableDebug` in terminal then configure debug as the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-maven-eclipse#debug-the-function-in-eclipse) says.

If acceptable, we could turn to IntelliJ IDEA, where we can terminate the process in one click.

Comment: I think you are referring to TM Terminal.
Yeah it worked with TM terminal. It is not ideal but does the job. Thank you

Comment: Have been an eclipse Fan so long. I am not sure where to start with IntelliJ :)

Comment: Thanks for correcting the typo. Azure function is just a small part of our usage so it doesn't hurt. Keep having fun with eclipse ;)

Comment: About IntelliJ: it has exactly the same issue. Also in IJ you have to use similar workarounds or go in Task Manager to kill some kind of func.exe that never end.

Comment: And 3 years later... the same applies